# How to get all the aspx page list of a given web address

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to create a list of all aspx pages contained in my website.

but i am getting only 40 pages. but there are more than 2000 pages.

Kindly tell me how can i get all the aspx page list.
I am using the following code to get url pages list.

```
private string[] GetAllUrls(string str) 
{ 
    string pattern = @"<a.*?href=[""'](?<url>.*?)[""'].*?>(?<name>.*?)</a>";

    System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(str, pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
    string[] matchList = new string[matches.Count]; 
    int c = 0; 

    foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches) 
        matchList[c++] = match.Groups["url"].Value; return matchList; 
}
```

Comment: How do you know there are 2,000 pages?

Comment: How are you getting those 40 pages? Show what you've tried.

Comment: Paste the code please, to know how you are trying to do it

Comment: private string[] GetAllUrls(string str)
        {
            string pattern = @"<a.*?href=[""'](?<url>.*?)[""'].*?>(?<name>.*?)</a>";

            System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches
                = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(str, pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            string[] matchList = new string[matches.Count];

            int c = 0;

            foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches)
                matchList[c++] = match.Groups["url"].Value;

            return matchList;
        }

Comment: i am using the above code to get urls.

Comment: Post as an answer not as a comment.

Comment: add from the html you're trying to parse a link that you would expect to show up but doesn't. Your real question is in that case: Why doesn't this <a href="some url" />  doens't match the regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you are getting these 40 files, but you can do this:

```
String[] Files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\YourSorceCodeDirectory", "*.aspx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: thanks Lukinha RS
 but i want to retrive all the url from server not from my local machine.

Comment: I got it. But this code will search from server. If your web application is published in your server, this "C:\" will be your server drive to search.