# C# - List all .aspx pages in a domain

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to write a console app that lists all of the aspx pages in a domain, there's about 50 or 60 pages and I'm all out of ideas on how to list them.

The pages are not hosted locally and I have no access to them apart from the login page, all I was given was the list of sites to output and so far, I've tried using the following approaches to no avail:

[How to get all the aspx page list of a given web address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415519/how-to-get-all-the-aspx-page-list-of-a-given-web-address)

Examples section here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapnode.aspx

I was thinking of using the HTTP classes in System.Web but this is the first time I've worked with .aspx and have very little knowledge of them.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [web crawler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was just about to say it. :)

Comment: Is Directory list available on the site?

Comment: @RobertHarvey If various pages are only accessible by successfully getting past another aspx, it's not going to give a full list.

Comment: Do you have any details on the site you intend to crawl?  With route mapping, the (virtual) .aspx pages could (effectively) be infinite.

Comment: All I have is the site name, port number and list of directories and sub directories to return. I'll be running validation against them but I'm having trouble connecting my program to the site itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the command line command

```
wget --recursive --http-user=user --http-password=password --accept=.aspx www.hostname.com
```

as it works like a web crawler.

I think it allows you to log in to pages too.

Comment: I'm getting a 302 redirect response when I use your command, I'm thinking the security on our site does not allow anyone to run crawlers, when a request is made to any page on the site, the response is to redirect to the login page.

Regardless, your answer is appreciated and since it's a problem on my end I'm marking it as a correct answer